# Download App Link in Google Search Results

Tags: android, download, google-search

I've an Android app, in which I enabled App indexing and Deep Linking, that app is associated with a company website, my target is to show "Download App" button when the site occurs in google's search results on a mobile phone or tablet like the pic attached.

Any orientations please ?

[image]

Comment: What issue you are getting exactly? Is your app is not appearing like apps in screenshot you have attached?

Comment: Yes, my site is apearing in search results, but not showing that there's an app associated within like booking.com or tripadvisor, I followed instructions from here : https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html but nothing happens

Comment: Have you tried this https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html this is exact what you want!

Comment: Yes, but this launches the app if installed to handle urls coming from search results, that works but in search results, I dont have "download App" if it wasn't already installed.

Comment: okay these are promotion campaigns. In actual apps search result you have attached are `ADs` or `Annonce`. more you can find here: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6309967?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as **App Indexing** on Google Search. Which allows developer to get their apps in google search result.

**How this works?**

If users already have installed your app then it will directly launch application. If user don't yet have your app then relevant google search query will create **install card** for your app in search result.

**Steps**
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6041489?hl=en

Comment: I've done all of this, and I've more than 600 pages indexed, but still no install card under indexed product link in search results :(